# how to change the size of text input element in a mobile application?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm designing an application for mobile in which I am trying to change the size of html text element. But "size" attribute is not showing any impact.
How can I do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To change the size dynamically, use the [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method from jQuery:

```
$("#element").css({
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});
```

Or another way without jQuery:

```
with (document.getElementById("element").style) {
    width = "100px";
    height = "100px";
}
```

---

To set static size use CSS `width` and `height` properties.

Answer (score 0):

The `size` attribute is an ancient relic.

Use CSS to define the `input` element's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" />
```

CSS

```
.input-text
{
width:300px;
height:30px;
font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: hi cgvector, I'm facing problem in a mobile application. This solution is not showing any impact there. Is this due to mobile css which i m using??

Comment: i have also use same code for mobile device application. and please add these 2 line also

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

Comment: sorry but I am still getting the same problem. I m using jquerymobile css